# How can I create a modal with a loop object in JavaScript and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, api, bootstrap-modal

hy, i have school project and i want to create modal,

i create an array empty for taking information, and i write it with an loop for taking information of my artist

`<body onload="runScripts()">

## ARTISTES

var artists = [];

```
function runScripts() {
  displayArtists();
}

function displayArtists() {
  artists.forEach(artist => {
    console.log(artist);
  });


}
```

## THIS IS THE BIG ARTIST IN THE WORLD

{{range .}}

```
artists.push({
  "id": "{{ .ID }}",
  "image": "{{ .Image }}",
  "name": "{{ .Name }}",
  "Members": "{{ .Members }}",
  "firstAlbum": "{{ .FirstAlbum }}",
  "creationDate": "{{ .CreationDate }}",
  "relations": "{{ .Getrelation }}"
  
  
});
```

{{end}}`

i have this output :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9IBr.png)

and i want to create modal with this. for this i try many attemps,

i search on stack but i don't understand the code, he his the code i see but dos'ent work : i have try many many, this [this is my history Lmao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELVT0.png) the list is long :( thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.